# How to pass a variable in python with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables

I have a data set like this :

```
Id  1456    1457    1458    1459    1460
MSSubClass  60  20  70  20  20
MSZoning    RL  RL  RL  RL  RL
LotFrontage 62  85  66  68  75
LotArea 7917    13175   9042    9717    9937
Street  Pave    Pave    Pave    Pave    Pave
Alley   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
LotShape    Reg Reg Reg Reg Reg
LandContour Lvl Lvl Lvl Lvl Lvl
```

I converted the strings to pandas. Now I need to convert them numerical data. To convert it into numerical data I take the output of following:

```
display_all(df_raw.isnull().sum().sort_index()/len(df_raw))
1stFlrSF         0.000000
2ndFlrSF         0.000000
3SsnPorch        0.000000
Alley            0.937671
BedroomAbvGr     0.000000
BldgType         0.000000
BsmtCond         0.025342
BsmtExposure     0.026027
BsmtFinSF1       0.000000
```

Where ever the value is non-zero, I convert it to numerical values.

```
train_cats(df_raw) #convert strings to pandas
op1=df_raw.isnull().sum().sort_index()/len(df_raw)
i=0
while i < op1.shape[0]:
    if op1[i]!=0.0:
        variabe_name=op1.index[i]
        df_raw.variable_name = df_raw.variable_name.cat.codes <----
    i+=1
```

So the raw value of this where Alley is non-zero would be : 
df_raw.alley = df_raw.alley.cat.codes

Alley needs to be passed as a variable name.

My question is how can I pass a variable name there instead of value so that I can loop through it? I tried @variable_name but it just gives me errors/

Maybe I am doing this wrong. Would there be a better way of doing this?

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use brackets for assignment: `df_raw[variable_name] = ...`

Comment: @James Does not work. df_raw[y] gives totally different kind of data compared to df_raw.y and when I try to convert it to code using df_raw.y.cat.codes I get an error "Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype"

Comment: @James I played around and you are correct. If y="Alley", then df_raw.[y] is equal o df_raw.Alley. It worked. Thanks a lot!!!!